# Dropbox "Send Intent" does not contain Stream data

Tags: android, android-intent, dropbox

I am trying to receive the content of the "share intent" send from dropbox. It Works in all other apps I have tested with the following code:

```
if(Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(getIntent().getAction()))
{
    filePath = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
}
```

However, when sharing from Dropbox on Android, the filepath is always `null`.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll need to check `EXTRA_TEXT` as well, which, when the user uses that share option, will contain a share link to the file. (As opposed to when the user "exports" the file, in which case the local link to the file will be available in `EXTRA_STREAM`.)

Note that, as of Jelly Bean, you can also use `ClipData`.